# Electron: how to parse a large file without blocking render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to parse a relatively large file keeping UI responsive? I tried everything: `fs.readFile` and `readline`, first in render process, then in the main process, communicating with render through IPC, then in a separate child process, using the main process as an intermediator. I don't know what else I can do.

The problem is, when I parse a file, render stays blocked (doesn't react on clicks or anything else) and doesn't update. I want to show a progress of parsing in the UI, but it appears only in the very end, although I make about 1000 updates and see console logs running.

Does anybody know how to do it right or if it's even possible?

Comment: Given that Atom has a hard time with large files, I would say this might be a problem the platform hasn't solved yet.

Comment: try fs.createReadStream

Comment: David, I did it in the combination with `readline`.

Comment: You might also need to pipe it to your handler. Can you post the code showing what you have tried?